# Stopping Times of Markov Chains and invariant measures

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose $X_0, X_1, X_2, \ldots$ is a Markov chain on a compact metric space $(\Omega, \mathcal{B}, \mathbb{P})$.  Call its Markov generator $R f(x) = \mathbb{E}[f(X_1)\; | \; X_0=x]$ ($f$ bounded measurable on $\Omega$).

Let $0 = \tau_0 < \tau_1 < \tau_2 < \cdots$ be a sequence of stopping times which are almost surely finite, and call the Markov chain at these stopping times $Y_k = X_{\tau_k}$.  Call its generator $L$.

My question is this.  If there exists an $R$-invariant measure $\mathbb{Q}$ on $\Omega$, so that $\int Rf d\mathbb{Q} = \int f d\mathbb{Q}$, is $\mathbb{Q}$ necessarily $L$-invariant?

I'm having trouble proving this.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: Consider a finite state space. Take the times so that L is actually constant. Then only in very trivial situations will the two measures agree.